# Swift container ViewPager

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in iOS, I recently started using Swift 2 and I need help with some stuff. Here is an image that can explain more what I need:
[image]

Well I need like some kind of container in the middle of the `viewcontroller` and add  two buttons to change the view (tap gesture too of course) and add the custom page control you see in the image.

Sorry I know I am asking too much  but any help or guide you know can help me will be very appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply way is to use the [UIPageViewController](https://github.com/Weijay/UIPageViewController). 
However, if you want to customise your own like that. You have to replace your container View in the center of your view controller.

```
// In viewDidLoad
{
  self.addChildViewController(customViewContoller1)

  customViewContoller1.view.frame = .. your position

  self.view.addSubview(customViewContoller1.view)
  customViewContoller1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

// Swipe Event: remove original vc
customViewContoller1.removeFromParentViewController()
// add new vc
self.addChildViewController(customViewContoller2)
self.view.addSubview(customViewContoller2.view)
```